# Semantic UI modal content for non-javascript users

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, progressive-enhancement

I'm looking for a way to use Semantic UI modals in a progressively enhancement way - that is, if JavaScript is enabled, the modal will display on page load, but if JavaScript is not enabled, I want the content of the modal to display inline on the page.

Right now I have the following:

```js
$(function () {

  // http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html
  $('.ui.modal.autoshow').modal('show');

});
```

```html
<h1>Something something something something darkside</h1>

<div>
  <p>whatever content here</p>
</div>

<div class="ui autoshow modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui tiny image">
      <i class="massive icon user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">Title</div>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="ui positive icon close button">
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is designed to automatically display the modal.

I'm thinking it might be possible to replace the `modal` class in the source code with one called `becomes-modal`, then update the JavaScript to replace all instances of `becomes-modal` with `modal` as soon as the page loads, before any other JavaScript gets run, allowing for the above functionality to work.

My reasoning is that if JavaScript is disabled, `becomes-modal` won't be swapped out for `modal`, meaning it won't be hidden by default, allowing for the content to display inline.

The problem is, I'm not sure if this is the right approach, or how I would go about doing it.

Comment: It's very difficult to say what the "right" approach is. What is your modal about? If it contains some information the user should see, then perhaps the simplest idea is to create a `<div class="noscript">information</div>` element (or several of them) containing this information, then calling `$('.noscript').hide();` at the same time you call `$('.ui.modal.autoshow').modal('show');`